# Regular Expression unexpected character

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I generated a small regular expression that should check input text to be in one of the following format.

- 00:00
- 00 :00
- 00 : 00
- 00: 00

Or even using the `.` in replace of the `:` (ie.: 00.00).

So I generated the following:

```
([01]?[0-9]{1}|2[0-3]{1})\u0020*[:.]\u0020*[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}
```

I used the tool here: http://regexr.com/ and everything seems to be ok.

Now I used it in my angular expression input via `ng-pattern="..."` but I receive the following error in the console:

```
Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 25-25 [\] in expression [([01]?[0-9]{1}|2[0-3]{1})\u0020*[:.]\u0020*[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}].
```

What I did wrong in it?

**EDIT:**

Take a look here: http://regexr.com/3ccn5

It seems to be ok, but using it with AngularJS it allow wrong inputs and even if I type: 22:2222222 for Angular it is correct... What's going on with it?

Comment: Sidenote: You don't need `{1}`

Comment: I think you need to double ``\`` with `\\u`.

Comment: not working at all using double `//`

Comment: Just put a space.. `([01]?[0-9]{1}|2[0-3]{1}) *[:.] *[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}`

Comment: How are you putting it in the ng-pattern attribute? Try `ng-pattern="/^([01]?[0-9]{1}|2[0-3]{1})\u0020*[:.]\u0020*[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}$/"`

Comment: I solved wrapping the entire regex within `/` and adding `\b` at the end of it:
`/([01]?[0-9]{1}|2[0-3]{1})\u0020*[:.]\u0020*[0-5]{1}[0-9]\b/`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the `\u0020` with a simple space . There is no need to escape the space character, and there is always a danger when passing regular expressions around as strings that you will have problems with the string interpreting the backslash instead of the regexp engine.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to double the \ for it to work:

```
([01]?[0-9]{1}|2[0-3]{1})\\u0020*[:.]\\u0020*[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}
```

Comment: It doesn't work doing that way... take a look at my update please.